# python while true can't keep it to loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm still learning python

but i ran into an error that's weird , i can get the while true to loop but the sub while true can't

i can only go back to the beginning , i don't know what i'm doing wrong , (( this is my third day of coding i have finished some course online in the past 2 days ))

```
def total(W):
print("ur total is :  ", W)

at = ""
att = ""

V = 0   
enter = ""

while enter == "":
enter = input ("choose A or T")
if enter.lower().startswith("a"):
    enter = input(" Enter An integer or 'Q' for quitting : ")
    if enter.lower() == "q":
        total(V);
    elif enter.isdigit():
        while enter.isdigit():


            att = at +"\n"+ enter
            at = att


            V = V + int(enter)

            enter = input(" Add anything else or Q for quiting : ")
            if enter.lower() == "q":
                print("items : \n-------\n  ",att)
                print ( "Total = ",V)
            elif enter.isdigit() == False:
      #   >>> i can't make it loop :S
                print (" error try again ")




# >>>      can't loop this too :S          
    else:
        print(enter ,"  is invalid!! ")
        enter = "apple"


elif enter.lower().startswith("t"):
    enter = input(" Enter An integer or 'Q' for quitting : ")

    if enter.isdigit():
        while enter.isdigit:
            V = V + int(enter)
            enter = input ("anything else or Q for quiting: ")
            if enter.lower() == "q":
                print ("total :", V)

    else:
        print(enter ,"  is invalid! ")
        enter.lower().startswith("t")



else:
    print(enter ,"  is invalid ")
    enter = ""
```

Comment: Mind the indent. Every code block must be indented.

Comment: That's a lot of code! Can you boil it down to short example that shows the problem?

Comment: Perhaps if you can explain what your code does or what you're trying to accomplish, maybe it will help people understand it better.  It doesn't help with indentation is all out of order so it's really hard to understand.